# Why is "and" evaluated before "equal"

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

In Javascript [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) of `strict equal` (10) is greater than `logical and` (6) then how does this code works

```js
var a;
console.log("value of a is", a);
if (a && a.test === "test") {}
```

Should it not throw error

> cannot read test of undefined.

And to add salt to the wound precedence of `member access` is higher than both of them (19).

What am i missing?

Comment: `a` is `undefined`, so it is "falsy" and the shortcut evaluation does not get to `a.test`

Comment: No, `a` is defined, its property `test` is undefined

Comment: @LarsBeck nope, see https://jsfiddle.net/f6ybjety/

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, @kalsowerus i do understand that `shortcut evaluation` does not let it reach the second half of expression, but my question is why is operator precedence not followed here. Should it not first evaluate `member access` then `strict equal` and then `logical and`?

Comment: @Claies value of `a` is `undefined` as i've not set any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programming languages, like JavaScript, evaluate logical expressions lazily. This means that if the first part of your expression (`a`) is false, the interpreter sees no reason for even executing the second part (`a.test === "test"`) and thus no error is thrown.

To clarify, precedence does not define the actual order in which an expression is executed, only the effective order. So that the `member access` operator hast highest precedence does not mean it will be executed first. The interpreter can still evaluate `a` first, without affecting the outcome of any of the higher precedence operators. You can think of precedence as implicit brackets, if you write the expression as `(a) && ((a.test) === "test")` you can clearly see that `a` can and will be evaluated first, as it is at the very left of expression.

Comment: Last line sounds interesting. Can you shed some more light on it.

Comment: If that is the case then why not increase the precedence of logical operators and make it more clear.

Comment: @a1626 because they do not have higher precedence, the `&&` is executed last, but does not have to be executed at all in certain situations.

Comment: Sorry, this is getting really confusing as far as i understand, if `&&` is not executed at all then code should not have known that RHS should not be executed. As far as i understand as per `short-circuit` it saw `false && (unevaluated code)` and gave result as false.

Comment: @a1626 Yes, exactly. And because when it sees that, then precedence of the unevaluated code does not matter anymore.

Comment: Ok. i think i understand it now. Ideally, first `left side` is evaluated then `right side` is evaluated and then `&&` is evaluated that's where precedence comes in. But if left side is false right is not evaluated (short-circuit). This still looks like a little off from precedence table as during the whole operation interpreter always knew there was `&&` and gave it higher precedence over RHS (even though it makes more practical sense).

Answer (score 1):

what that table means is that in an expression like that the elements are evaluated as

`a && (a.test === 'something')` and not as `(a && a.test) === 'something'`

because of the order of precedence.this is totally independent on how the logical expressions are evaluated(in order of appearance). so if `a` is false there is no reason to evaluate the rest of the expression because no matter what lies after the `&&` the expression will be false. same thing would happen if `a` was `true` and the operator was `||`. this is also known as short-circuit.

Comment: If that is the case then why not increase the precedence of logical operators and make it more clear.

Comment: because the euqality applies to any data type and returns a bollean if you increase the precedence of the  logical operators `&&` you would be forcing the language to then use the grouping every time  you want to perform a comparison and combine the result so what now is `a===1 && b===2 && c===3` would have to be written `(a===1) && (b===2) && (c===3)`  otherwise would be interpreted `a===(1&&b) ===(2&&c) ===3` as you can see something like this would either be very verbose or very confusing.

Comment: Great example to explain it.

Comment: glad to be of help